# Proof of basic set theory problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

In my book I have to prove the following statement:
Suppose A and B are sets, prove that
$$
\mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A\cup B)
$$

Please correct me if I am wrong I do not have much experience and am very new to this field.

So far I have:

$$ \{x\} \in (\mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B)) $$
$$ \{x\} \in \mathcal{P}(A) \text{ or } \{x\} \in \mathcal{P}(B) $$
$$ \{x\} \subseteq A \text{ or } \{x\} \subseteq B $$
$$ x \in A \text{ or } x \in B $$
$$ x \in (A \cup B) $$
$$ \{x\} \subseteq (A \cup B) $$
$$ \{x\} \in \mathcal{P}(A \cup B) $$
$$\text{since } \{x\} \in (\mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B)) \text{ and } \{x\} \in \mathcal{P}(A \cup B) $$
$$\text{ it follows, that } \\ \mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A \cup B) $$

It is no homework and I have no Teacher to talk to, can you please correct me or tell me if or where I am wrong ? 
I appreciate any help. 
(I am doing the book called Proofs by Jay Cummings Chapter 3, Exercise 3.15)

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: How do you know there is an element in P(A) ∪ P(B) of the form {x}? Your proof has holes that need justification. Hint: Case 1: If (P(A) ∪ P(B) ) is the empty set, it is automatically a subset- because the empty set is a subset of any set. Case 2: If (P(A) ∪ P(B)) is not the  empty set, let x be an element in (P(A) ∪ P(B)). Try continuing from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you want to use a few words in each line to explain your reasoning.  Secondly, as has been pointed out in the comments, you seem to be assuming every member of the power set has the form $\{x\}$, which is not true.

Still, there is a germ of the correct idea in your chain of reasoning.  You can reason as follows:

1. Let $S \in \mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B)$.
2. Then by the definition of unions, $S\in \mathcal{P}(A)$ or  $S\in  \mathcal{P}(B)$.
3. Then by the definition of the power set, $S\subseteq A$ or $S\subseteq B$.
4. Then for all $x\in S$, by the definition of subsets, $x\in A$ or $x\in B$.
5. Then by the definition of unions, for all $x\in S$, $x\in A\cup B$.
6. Then by the definition of subsets, $S\subseteq A\cup B$.
7. Then by the definition of the power set, $S\in \mathcal P(A\cup B)$.
8. Since we have shown $S\in \mathcal P(A) \cup \mathcal P(B)$ implies $S\in \mathcal P(A\cup B)$ for arbitrary $S$, we conclude that $\mathcal P(A) \cup \mathcal P(B)\subseteq \mathcal P(A\cup B)$ by the definition of subsets.

Later in mathematics, you will skip some of these steps.   For example, many mathematicians would simply go from 3 to 6 by saying "Since $S\subseteq A$ or $S\subseteq B$, we have $S\subseteq A\cup B$" viewing the chain of reasoning as obvious, and even more advanced mathematicians would simply consider "$\mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A\cup B)$" itself to be obvious and need no justification, but at the beginner level that you are at, you really need to justify every step.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much !!! I got it.